# asp.net process model/parallel processing

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, iis-7

I have a rather unusual web application. Some tasks(mainly analytical processes ) can take several minutes. Knowing that by default i only have one worker process processing requests, will the long processing time mean that any other request on the site will be put on a queue for waiting until the long running task has completed?

What would be the best multi tasking/multi threading approach given that individual process would have to share session informations?

many thanks in advance

B

Comment: `Knowing that by default i only have one thread processing requests` What makes you think that?  By default you'll most likely have quite a few threads processing requests.

Comment: How do i know the number of threads? I meant one worker process by the way.

Comment: You shouldn't *need* to know the number of threads, nor will it be static.  It will create/destroy threads as needed, that's the way thread pools work.

Comment: So why is there ever needed to increase the number of working processes? Why does the application block on some request when some heavy processing is taking place?

Comment: More threads isn't necessarily better.  If the hardware is fully utilized creating additional threads doesn't increase throughput at all.

Comment: I was referring to the need to create additional worker processes. Not threads

Comment: @Servy is right though. If CPU is maxed, increased threads or worker processes makes 0 difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worker process hosts a number of threads. This is defined in the [`<processModel>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) section of `Machine.config` and I believe defaults to around 128 request listeners and 128 thread pool threads. So, other threads will be able to do work while a thread is tied up, but the tied up thread may cause CPU to be used which will degrade the other threads' performance.

Comment: In our case, the busy thread seem to deprive all the other threads from any cpu time. No one can do much on the site in some cases. Does this make sense or do we have some other serious issue?

Comment: That's because you have X CPU and if 1 thread uses 100% of it the rest get blocked. You likely have architecture problems...

Comment: number crunching through stored procedures on the database

Comment: You need to crunch those numbers periodically ahead of the request, and have the request just serve the latest results (could be delayed by, for example, up to an hour). Then you won't use nearly the same amount of CPU. The crunched results could be stored in a table of their own perhaps.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but the parameters needed for the crunching are provided when the user is logged on and working. So I believe we have to dramatically change the way things work. I suspect with have to implement a command design pattern as used by amazon.com when to process orders. The order is taken and  you get a message that your order has been received and will be processed. The actual work put in queue and is done later. We have just been very optimistic to believe otherwise and hoping that you could process as you go in a web application. We probably need a redesign

Comment: Exactly! That or a different paradigm. Would it work better in a NoSQL key-value-pair structure? Or a search engine structure like Lucene.net? SQL is ubiquitous in our field, but it isn't always the best possible answer. Glad the discussion helped! :)